# Selecting checkbox using xpath for a particular attribute

Tags: xpath

I'm using selenium to automate the testing. I'm facing an issue when I try to select the checkbox having title as "1794 Pecos Rd, Las Vegas NV 89115, UNITED STATES" of a below table row. So I'm using XPath to do this. Below is the HTML.

```
<tr class="odd" role="row">
    <td class="sorting_1" title="<input type="checkbox">">
        <input type="checkbox" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    </td>
    <td title="1206164015">1206164015</td>
    <td title="1794 Pecos Rd, Las Vegas NV 89115, UNITED STATES">1794 Pecos Rd, Las Vegas NV 89115, UNITED STATES</td>
</tr>
```

Below is the XPATH that I have tried:

```
//*[@title="110 Pennington St, Tuscon AZ 85701, UNITED STATES"]/preceding-sibling::td/input
```

Comment: Have you tried using `contains()`? Basically `//*[contains(@title,"110 Pennington St, Tuscon AZ 85701, UNITED STATES")]/preceding-sibling::td/input`.

Comment: `"1794 Pecos Rd, Las Vegas NV 89115, UNITED STATES"` is not `"110 Pennington St, Tuscon AZ 85701, UNITED STATES"`... show correct examples

Comment: For selecting title "110 Pennington St, Tuscon AZ 85701, UNITED STATES" check box, used xpath as //*[contains(@title,"110 Pennington St, Tuscon AZ 85701, UNITED STATES")]/preceding-sibling::td/input  but no luck!

Comment: @SudhakarReddy  are you facing any error ? can you show up your code ?